How do I prove that this vector field is 0 everywhere?
I will give all the things I know, some of them may be useless in the proof.
(if there is one).
I have an open bounded connected set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ such that every contained closed surface is boundary of some contained 3-manifold and such that divergence theorem holds, and a vector field $v$ such that $v \in C(\mathbb{R}^3) \cap C^1(\Omega) \cap C^1(\mathbb{R}^3-\bar{\Omega})$, and $\nabla \times v = \nabla \cdot v = 0$ in $\Omega \cup (\mathbb{R}^3-\bar{\Omega})$ and such that $|v(x)| = O(|x|^{-2})$.
I want to conclude that $v = 0$ everywhere, how do I do this?

Maybe the Helmholtz-Decomposition is of some use. You should mention your other question that this is related to and the book you are following.
